# Thirumangai alwar

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, alwar, saint

What are the special characteristics of  this alwar and how many names was given to him by almighty? What is his significant contribution towards Vaishnavism ?

Comment: Parthasarathy , you should ask in Parthasarathy kovil :) in Thiruallikkeni, they will give authentic answer (I assume u know Tamil), or u can see this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8padrcq-f00

Comment: @Mr.Ram, For that I should go to Parthasarathy swamy temple. I think all the battccharyas do not know.